# Single Sign on for DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

We have an application that we currently open the DocuSign console in an IFrame. The issue is that currently we are having to open a new tab, log on to DocuSign and then the user can see the console in the Iframe with documents. What is the most common way people are using to automatically logon to DocuSign through their applications ? I see an SSO documentation but it says that it looks at the persons email domain to authenticate them.... our users will have many different email domains.

Answer (score 0):

Your application can use the API to get the console view for the user.  The session will correspond to the user credentials in your API request and will skip the logon step.  From that API call you get a URL back that you can embed in the iFrame.  E.g.:  POST to https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/55555/views/console and you get back a URL like this:

```
{
  "url": "https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&accountid=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
```

**Edit:** If you need the "sending view" (sometimes called "the tagger") for an envelope then you can POST using a URL like this:

```
https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender
```

e.g.

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/12345/envelopes/f6e755d3-bbcf-44e5-b276-8ae626f97220/views/sender
```

Comment: thanks.... I get the url back but it takes me directly to the login screen instead of just logging in. am I missing something ?

Comment: actually I got it to work correctly... it goes to the main envelope screen... I need it to go to the \add-fields page though... where in the return url would I need to add the \add-fields ?

Comment: You may be referring to the "Sender view" this is particularly useful for Draft envelopes.  I'll edit my response to include that.

Comment: so I am using the api walkthrough code for going to a console view and I changed the views/console to views/sender and I get a bad request error... it works fine to get the link for console but not sender... I also looked at the views sender walkthrough and it says it requires you to add a template id.. we wouldn't be using templates. The walkthrough I'm using is at http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedDocuSign.

Comment: in our current situation once we login we direct the user to this  string url = "https://appdemo.docusign.com/prepare/" + Model.EnvelopeId + "/add-fields"; This is the url we need to end up at after getting logged in.

Comment: also I followed your reference above for the sender view and it looks like this envelopes/f6e755d3-bbcf-44e5-b276-8ae626f97220/views/sender

Comment: What is the error message you are getting when you POST to views/sender?  Note: You shouldn't go directly to appdemo.docusign.com.  That isn't an API and not all users/accounts use that system.  That is why you are being prompted to authenticate.  If you use the API itself (views/sender) then you authenticate as part of the API call using the X-DocuSign-Authentication header.

Comment: so I switched back to try the api tester on the idocs page https://iodocs.docusign.com/ ... using the api to get to the console and it give me back a url that I plug into my browser and it logs me in fine no problem... then I copy the code directly from the API walkthrough to login to the console from the api walkthrough page...put it in a console app and it gives me back a url and I put that in the browser and it brings me to the login page. Is there some difference between what the tester on the idocs page and the walkthrough code on the walkthrough page for getting to the console ?

Comment: Those really should be using the exact same call.  Can you point me to what part of iodocs and which walkthrough you are using?  From our earlier comments it sounds like you need not the console login but the sender view, yes?

Comment: So I realize what it is.... the walkthrough code returns a url that has extra characters in it after the &... it sticks "AMP" in it. Once I compared the urls being returned from the walkthrough code and the Idoc tester... I removed the "AMP" from the url and it works great... thanks Jeff !